Being open inside a subspace
Consider the image below.

Now suppose $B \subseteq A \subseteq X$. When we say $B$ is open we mean either $B$ is $\tau$-open or $B$ is $\tau_A$ open. What does $B$ look like in relation to the linked pic in either case?
I think
If $B$ is $\tau$-open and entirely contained inside $A$, then $B$ is one of the dashed lane ovals that fits entirely inside $A$.
If $B$ is $\tau_A$-open and entirely contained inside $A$, then $B$ is a smaller shape inside A that intersects all the dashed lane ovals $A$ does. We can think of $B$ as a smaller version of $A$ that fits inside $A$.
Does that make sense?

No, what you wrote is wrong. Have you read the definition of $\tau_A$? Also, try to avoid the nonstandard terminology such as "inside".


If $B$ is $\tau$-open and entirely contained inside $A$, then $B$ is one of the dashed line ovals that fits entirely inside $A$.

Your idea is mostly correct. $B$ doesn't necessarily have to be "one of the dashed line ovals" in $A$. Rather, for any point $x$ of $B$, there exists some "dashed line oval" $U_x (\in \tau)$ containing $x$ such that $U_x \subseteq B$. (Note that this of course implies that $U_x \subseteq A$.) This is nothing but idea of a set being open in a topology.

If $B$ is $\tau_A$-open and entirely contained inside $A$, then $B$ is a smaller shape inside $A$ that intersects all the dashed line ovals $A$ does.

This is not correct. If $B$ is open in $A$ endowed with the subspace topology ($\tau_A$), it means that there exists some $B' \in \tau$ such that $B = A \cap B'$. This is the same as saying that for any point $x$ of $B$, there exists some "dashed line oval" $U_x (\in \tau)$ containing $x$ such that $A \cap U_x \subseteq B$. Note that unlike the previous case, $U_x$ does not need to be a subset of $A$ (it only needs to satisfy that its intersection with $A$ is contained in $B$). There is of course no requirement that "$B$ intersects all the dashed line ovals $A$ does."

To summarize in my own words: First case: Every point in $B$ has a neighborhood $N$ that fits in $B$ and $N$ is sourced out of $\tau$. Second case: Same as the first case except the neighborhoods around the interior points must intersect $A$ as well. Correct?

Since $B \subset X,$  can $B$ simply be in $\tau$?

Right idea for the first case (that is just the definition of $B$ being open in $(X, \tau)$). For the second point: the neighborhood $N$ of $x \in B$ need not be contained in $B$, but its intersection with $A$ must be contained in $B$.

To your second comment: not necessarily. Some sets that are open in $\tau_A$ might not be open in $\tau$. Remember, a set $B$ is open in $\tau_A$ if there exists some $B' \in \tau$ such that $B = A \cap B'$. If $B' \subseteq A$, then $B = B'$, and of course $B \in \tau$. But there is no requirement for $B' \subseteq A$.
